# Mensagem da controller para a view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Fiz isso:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void CadastraUsusario(string _nome, string _usuario, string _email, string _nivel_acesso, bool _ativo)
        {
            using (RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities())
            {
                Usuario usu = new Usuario();
                try
                {
                    var retorna_usuario = db.Usuario
                                          .Where(u => u.NM_Usuario == _nome && u.Usuario1 == _usuario)
                                          .Select(d => new { d.NM_Usuario, d.Usuario1 }).ToList();

                    if (retorna_usuario == null)
                    {
                        usu.NM_Usuario = _nome;
                        usu.Usuario1 = _usuario;
                        usu.Email = _email;
                        usu.NivelAcesso = _nivel_acesso;
                        usu.Ativo = _ativo;
                        db.Usuario.Add(usu);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.MsgError = "Usuário já está cadastrado no sistema.";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }
```

Como eu faço para quando a minha linq retornar algo, eu não prossigo com a inserção e disparo a mensagem na tela do usuário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementando um `@helper` para mandar mensagens *Flash* para a tela.

Implementei um assim:

### App_Code/Flash.cshtml

Estou supondo que você usa jQuery para o seu projeto:

```
@helper FlashMessage(System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary tempData) 
{
    var message = "";
    var className = "";
    if (tempData["info"] != null)
    {
        message = tempData["info"].ToString();
        className = "flashInfo";
    }
    else if (tempData["warning"] != null)
    {
        message = tempData["warning"].ToString();
        className = "flashWarning";
    }
    else if (tempData["error"] != null)
    {
        message = tempData["error"].ToString();
        className = "flashError";
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#flash').html('@message');
            $('#flash').toggleClass('@className');
            $('#flash').slideDown('slow');
            $('#flash').click(function(){$('#flash').toggle('highlight')});
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```

### Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Coloque uma `<div>` com o `id = "flash"`, que servirá para exibir a mensagem, mais a chamada ao `helper`, que montará um JavaScript em tempo de execução no seu *Layout*:

```
<div id="body">
    @Flash.FlashMessage(TempData)
    <div id="flash"></div>
    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">@RenderBody()</section>
</div>
```

### Helpers/FlashHelper.cs

Isto é uma *Extension* de *Controller*:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Helpers
{
    public static class FlashHelper
    {

        public static void FlashInfo(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            controller.TempData["info"] = message;
        }
        public static void FlashWarning(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            controller.TempData["warning"] = message;
        }
        public static void FlashError(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            controller.TempData["error"] = message;
        }
    }
}
```

## Uso

Use dentro do seu *Controller* o seguinte:

```
this.FlashInfo("Mensagem de Informação.");
this.FlashWarning("Mensagem de Aviso.");
this.FlashError("Mensagem de Erro.")
```

Comment: Não consegui ainda enviar uma mensagem do controller para a view e exibir na página do usuário.

Comment: Você implementou todos os passos? Como ficou seu código? Você inspecionou a `<div id="flash">` ao testar?

Comment: Veja se é isso. Você criou uma view chamada Flash.cshtl. Depois na view _Layout.cshtml você fez as alterações devidas. Criou uma classe chamada FlashHelper.cs e aí dentro da controller que no meu caso, fará a regra e a mensagem, colocou as 3 linhas(Uso) que você fe. Se foi isso, não conseguir fazer funcionar, inclusive procurei criar exatamente como você disse, até os folders que eu não tenho os criei para ficar exatamente como você colocou aqui.

Comment: Você pode atualizar a pergunta com o código implementado?