# Apresentando mensagem em uma view através do Controller C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

buscando uma solução encontrei uma forma no link [Mensagem da controller para a view](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31239/mensagem-da-controller-para-a-view/106849#106849)

Porém o meu problema é que não é apresentado nada. Não sei se é por que não tenho uma ação na View mas a mensagem não aparece.

A estrutura está montada desta forma (a estrutura base do link anterior foi mantida e montada praticamente igual):

---

Controller

```
public ActionResult Relatorios()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Mensagem";
            ViewBag.TipoUser = 1;

            this.FlashInfo(this, "Mensagem de Informação.");
            this.FlashWarning("Mensagem de Aviso.");
            this.FlashError("Mensagem de Erro.");
        }
```

Dentro da View eu só tenho o seguinte código:

---

```
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Relatórios";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

---

Gerenciamento de Relatórios

Dentro de `_Layout` coloquei dentro do seguinte segmento

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px">
    @Flash.FlashMessage(TempData)
    <div id="flash">
    </div>  
    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
    <footer style="margin-top: 10px">
       <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Empresa</p>
    </footer>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inputmask")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/maskedinput")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer escrever o conteúdo de `ViewBag.Message` na sua pagina? se for é só colocar `@ViewBag.Message`na view. Não entendi bem o que você quer.

Comment: Na realidade, montei a estrutura oferecida pelo link anexo, tudo funciona "aparentemente" pelo debug não apresenta erro, porém também não apresenta a mensagem. Não sei se é por causa que o controler não tem uma ação ou submit mas fiz um teste incluindo isso e mesmo assim não apresentou a mensagem.

Comment: Você inspecionou o conteúdo do HTML pra ver se a mensagem foi escrita nele? Pode ser apenas um problema de exibição.

Comment: Faz isso que o @Cigano falou. Se ainda assim não achar, você pode fazer outro teste, está vendo aquele `@DateTime.Now.Year` ali no final do Layout? Você vê ele no HTML? Se ver, coloca o `@ViewBag.Message` ali do lado dele. A mensagem deve aparecer colada na data, pelo menos vai te dar uma luz de como funciona a view

Comment: Quando coloquei ViewBag.Message ao lado do @DateTime funcionou, mas o método FlashInfo por exemplo não aparece. Imagina que tenho várias ações dentro do controller e ao final gostaria de apresentar uma mensagem do tipo Alert com a informação FlashInfo("Processo realizado com sucesso"), dentro do controller não passando a Viewbag ou algo similar mas que apresenta a mensagem, por isso vi o tópico e fiz a implementação.

Comment: Tentando resolver a situação, tentei levar a <div = "Flash"></div> para a view e Flash.FlashMessage(TempData) para a view removendo do _Layout e também não funcionou. Nada é apresentado. E como se ele ignorasse o javascript do helper. Acho !

Comment: Fazendo o debug, pude notar que ele entra no Flash.cshtml, testa o conteúdo e passa informando que não é nulo, processa o javascript e retorna para view, depois ele processa o _Layout e quando termina não mostra nada.

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas formas.
Implementei uma solução bem simples e você pode ter acesso a ela através deste [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h8Hr1w)

Por limitações da ferramenta não fiz uso de herança, a qual eu recomendo fortemente o uso.

Sinta-se livre para estender esta simples solução.

Espero ter ajudado.

> **Update:** Vou colocar o código aqui para evitar futuros problemas como a quebra de link do dotnetfiddle, mas para visualização/execução
>   online manterei o [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h8Hr1w)

*MyDialog.cs*

```
namespace MyDialogMvcApp
{
    public class MyDialog
    {
        public enum DialogType : short {
            Info = 0,
            Success = 1,
            Warning = 2,
            Error = 3
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DialogType @Type { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{{ \"title\": \"{Title}\", \"content\": \"{Content}\", \"type\": \"{@Type.ToString().ToLower()}\" }}";
    }
}
```

*BaseController.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyDialogMvcApp
{
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public const string SystemMessage = "MY_DIALOG";

        protected void ShowMessage(string htmlContent, string htmlTitle = "Mensagem do Sistema", MyDialog.DialogType type = MyDialog.DialogType.Info)
        {
            this.ShowMessage(new MyDialog{ Title = htmlTitle, Content = htmlContent, @Type = type});
        }

        protected void ShowMessage(MyDialog dialog)
        {
            this.TempData[SystemMessage] = dialog.ToString(); 
        }
    }
}
```

*HomeController.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyDialogMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            this.ShowMessage("Uma mensagem de teste =)");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

*Index.cshtml ou _Layout.cshtml (com o @RenderBody())*

```
@{  Layout = null; }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>E ai, cara!?</h1>
                <p>Espero que você tenha recebido um alerta quando a página carregou. ;)</p>
                <p>Caso não tenha notado, <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="aShowMessage">clique aqui</a> para que a mensagem seja exibida novamente.
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showMessage(message){
                toastr[message.type](message.content, message.title);
            }

            $(function(){
                var systemMessage = @Html.Raw(TempData[MyDialogMvcApp.BaseController.SystemMessage]);               

                showMessage(systemMessage);

                $('#aShowMessage').click(function(){ showMessage(systemMessage) });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```